# Issue with Visual C++ 2010 (Express) External Tools command

Tags: visual-studio-2010, make

Normally we develop in VS 2005 Pro, but I wanted to give VS 2010 a spin.
We have custom build tools based off of GNU make tools that are called when creating an executable.

This is the error that I see whenever I call my external tool:

```
...\gnu\make.exe): *** couldn't commit memory for cygwin heap, Win32 error 487
```

The caveat is that it still works perfectly fine in VS2005, as well as being called straight from the command line.  Also, my external tool is setup exactly the same as in VS 2005.

Is there some setting somewhere that could cause this error to be thrown?

Comment: wouldn't this be better on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [problem with heap, win32 error 487](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2001-07/msg00755.html) :

> Each Cygwin app gets a special heap
>   area to hold stuff which is inherited
>   to child processes. Eg. all file
>   descriptor structures are stored in
>   that heap area (called the "cygheap").
>   The cygheap has room for at least 4000
>   file descriptor structures. But -
>   that's the clue - it's fixed size. The
>   cygheap can't grow. It's size is
>   reserved at the application's start
>   and it's blocks are commited on
>   demand.
>
> For some reason your server
>   application needs all the cygheap
>   space when running under the described
>   conditions.

A possible solution might be found in [Changing Cygwin's Maximum Memory](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-maxmem.html):

> Cygwin's heap is extensible. However,
>   it does start out at a fixed size and
>   attempts to extend it may run into
>   memory which has been previously
>   allocated by Windows. In some cases,
>   this problem can be solved by adding
>   an entry in the either the
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (to change the
>   limit for all users) or
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER (for just the
>   current user) section of the registry.
>
> Add the DWORD value heap_chunk_in_mb
>   and set it to the desired memory limit
>   in decimal MB. It is preferred to do
>   this in Cygwin using the regtool
>   program included in the Cygwin
>   package. (For more information about
>   regtool or the other Cygwin utilities,
>   see the section called “Cygwin
>   Utilities” or use the --help option of
>   each util.) You should always be
>   careful when using regtool since
>   damaging your system registry can
>   result in an unusable system. This
>   example sets memory limit to 1024 MB:
>
> ```
> regtool -i set /HKLM/Software/Cygwin/heap_chunk_in_mb 1024
> regtool -v list /HKLM/Software/Cygwin
> ```
>
> Exit all running Cygwin processes and
>   restart them. Memory can be allocated
>   up to the size of the system swap
>   space minus any the size of any
>   running processes. The system swap
>   should be at least as large as the
>   physically installed RAM and can be
>   modified under the System category of
>   the Control Panel.

It wouldn't hurt to ensure that the maximum size of your windows swap file is large enough.

And by the way, how much RAM do you have in your computer?

Comment: 1.5gb of RAM...swap file is definitely big enough...i'll see if i can find where these settings are defined in our make process...there's no actual cygwin environment running at compile-time..its all windows exe's that are called

Comment: @espais: You are using the cygwin make. Was this by intent? Or can you switch to Microsoft's make?

Comment: nope...using the gnu tools is the department standard...what i was getting at was that all exe's are called in a non-cygwin environment (through some creative batch file scripting)

Comment: @espais: That creative environment doesn't allocate enough heap space for the cygwin executables. For some reason the problem is more acute with VS2010 Express. You need to either fix that environment, or use another Linux port, or use Microsoft utilities.

Comment: @harry - are you on StackOverflow as well?  I posted this question there as well...if you wish to answer for rep over there you can answer it...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008217/issue-with-visual-c-2010-express-external-tools-command

Comment: @espais: I did as you suggested, although I'm not very active on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is a problem with the Expressiveness versus the Professionalism of the version. You could try trying the [trial of the Professional version](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5414e4c0-c1f8-473e-8e9d-a1a7be786141&displaylang=en).

Comment: That wouldn't make any sense.